# please help me in lxml

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, lxml

I am facing some problem in scraping using lxml
I just made a code that is working fine but I have two problems

1. I want name and address in same row and every entry should be in different line like

   ```
   name1,adress1
   name2,adress2
   ```

i dont need any squar bracket in the data

2. I have to enter 500 codes so I want to import it from external text/csv file
   Please help me how can i do it

---

```
import lxml.html as lh

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

from lxml import html


for cod in ("35211","36116","36542"):

     browser.get('http://kmbsapps.konicaminolta.us/wheretobuy/main_search.jspx?productCategory=Office+Systems&sl_zip='+cod)

     content = browser.page_source

     tree = lh.fromstring(content)

     name=tree.xpath('//tr/td/span[@class="largecol"]/text()')

     adress=tre.xpath('//tr/td/span[@class="smallcol"]/text()')


     print(name,adress)
```

Comment: How does the text/csv look like?

Comment: it is in excell in column

Comment: I mean: what columns are there?

Comment: csv file is like
36116
36542
36693
35630
35802
35805
85719
85713
85040
85281
86301
72703

Comment: It's hard to tell what it is in the comment. Are they lines of single numbers (without header)?

Comment: yes they are single number(in verticle single column) without header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `lxml`, `selenium` does provide `find_elements_by_xpath`.

Use `zip` to match names and addresses.

Open the text file and iterate to get line; use `str.strip` to get the codes.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://kmbsapps.konicaminolta.us/wheretobuy/main_search.jspx?productCategory=Office+Systems&sl_zip='

with open('1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        cod = line.strip()
        browser.get(url+cod)
        name = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td/span[@class="largecol"]')
        address = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td/span[@class="smallcol"]')
        name = [n for n in name if n.text.strip()]  # Remove empty names
        for n, a in zip(name, address):
            print(n.text, a.text)
```

If what you want is not affected by javascript, you can just use `lxml` only.

```
import lxml.html

url = 'http://kmbsapps.konicaminolta.us/wheretobuy/main_search.jspx?productCategory=Office+Systems&sl_zip='

with open('1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        cod = line.strip()
        tree = lxml.html.parse(url+cod)
        name = tree.xpath('//tr/td/span[@class="largecol"]/text()')
        address = tree.xpath('//tr/td/span[@class="smallcol"]/text()')
        name = [n for n in name if n.strip()]
        for n, a in zip(name, address):
            print(n, a)
```

Comment: will i get results in seprate lines

Comment: @user3891081, Yes you will. Please try yourself. I gave you working codes.

Comment: I am still not getting data in separate line

Comment: this is the result                                                                 3.1 miles 660 University Boulevard, Suite H
Birmingham, AL 35233
AMERI-TEK 2814 Linden Avenue
Birmingham, AL 35209
4.0 miles 1101 Greenwood Crossing Court
Bessemer, AL 35022
DEX IMAGING OF ALABAMA, LLC 6205 AL Highway 69
Guntersville, AL 35976
9.8 miles 3240 Leeman Ferry Road
Huntsville, AL 35801
KONICA MINOLTA BUSINESS SOLUTIONS U.S.A., INC. 1523 South Broad Street
Scottsboro, AL 35233

Comment: @user3891081, Could you post it somewhere else (sites like pastebin)? It's hard to tell if there's newline or not by seeing the comment.

Comment: @user3891081, It should print in separate lines. Here's what I get: http://asciinema.org/a/12158

Comment: hi,I am still facing a problem.zip(name, address) is scraping different name with diff adress.can you please tell me how can i write filter code.i know how to do it in bs4 but I cant write that filter in lxml.please help me

Comment: Thanks again for your help.actually problem is solved.your code helped me lot(specially strip() function) and I learn  new things.Thanks again.